# Prove that a point $p$ is a limit point of $(a,b)$ iff $ p$ $\in [a,b]$.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Not really sure how to start this. I do know that I have to show the limit points of a set, show that p $\in$ S, and using $p < x < q$ shows that it's not a limit point. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Welp, it an iff.  Show a, and be are limit points.  Show a < p <b are limit points.  Shw p < a is not a limit point.  And p > b is not a limit point.  That is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

If $p < a$ then the open ball ( open interval ) centered at $p$ having radius $r = \dfrac{p+a}{2}$ would fail to intersect $(a,b)$. Thus $p \ge a$, and similarly $p \le b$. So $p \in [a,b]$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: in other words you have to show:

$ p \in [a,b]$ iff there is a sequence $(a_n)$ in $(a,b) \setminus \{p\}$ such that $a_n \to p$.